# Datastage Project Backup Automation

Tags: linux, datastage

I am using IBM IIS 11.3. I would like to automate the datastage project backup on daily basis. Can someone, share me how to write a Linux script that would list the projects by itself and take backup by itself?

Comment: I would suggest doing some searching online for examples and at least taking a stab at this yourself before asking for help here.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to export datastage jobs from Unix, but there is a way to automate the exporting(backup) jobs from projects using '*[dsexport](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZJPZ_9.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.ds.design.doc/topics/dsexportcommand.html)*' and '*[dscmdexport](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZJPZ_9.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.ds.design.doc/topics/dscmdexportcommand.html)*' utilities.

These tools are provided by IBM and they resides in "C:\IBM\InformationServer\Clients\Classic directory".

If you want to check an example, you can see the [automatic comparison of datastage jobs using *diffapicmdline* utility](http://wingsoftechnology.com/compare-datastage-etl-jobs-using-automated-script/). This way you can use export utilities also.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code to get you started:

```
# Export the name of all your Datastage projects
$DSHOME/bin/dsjob -lprojects > projectList.txt

while read projectName
do
  echo "Processing project $projectName"
  cd "/xxx/xxx/xxx/$projectName" # Your datastage project directory"

  # Export the name of all your Datastage jobs for this project
  $DSHOME/bin/dsjob -ljobs $projectName > ${projectName}_JobList.txt

  while read jobName
  do
    echo "Exporting job $jobName" of project $projectName
    $DSHOME/xxx/istool export -dom yourdomain -u yourusername -p yourpassword -ar /$[jobName}.isx -ds 'SERVER/${projectName}/*/*.* '
  done < ${projectName}_JobList.txt

done < projectList.txt
```